# How to dynamically get the value of a select tag from MySQL table

Tags: php, html, mysql

Thanks for dropping by and I'm sorry if this question seems to be easy as I'm kinda new to php. Im trying to do a school project and my problem now is that I cant seem to get the values of the  dropdown. I have been trying to search in every forum and some similar questions in here but they seem to only show how i can populate the dropdown with database values.

The code for populating the dropdown menu is working, but recording the selected value is not working for me.

Here is my php code for the dropdown:

```
<div class="panel">
    <label class="panelname">Category:</label>
    <select name="category" class="signup_field">
        <option>Select One</option>
        <? // retrieve all the categories and add to the pull down menu
        $query = 'SELECT category_id, name FROM category ORDER BY name ASC';
        $request = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($request, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
            $cat_id = $row[0];
            echo "<option value=\"row[0]\"";
            //check for stickyness:
            if (isset($_POST['category']) && ($_POST['category'] == $row[0])) {
                echo ' selected="selected"';
                //$_POST[]
            } echo ">$row[1]</option>\n";
        }
        ?>
    </select>
    <? if (array_key_exists('category', $add_product_errors)) echo '<label class="error">' . $add_product_errors['category'] . '</label>'; ?>
</div>
```

and here is my part of my code for validation: -

```
// Check for a form submission:
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

// Check for a category:
if (!isset($_POST['category']) || !filter_var($_POST['category'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array('min_range' => 1))) {
    $add_product_errors['category'] = 'Please select a category!';
} 
..... // other codes for validation (Eg: if (empty($add_product_errors)) { proceed to query} )
```

I don't know what seems to be the problem but there are no values recorded in the $_POST['category'] for me to save into MySQL and I keep getting the Please select a category error.

Thank you all for your help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, I seem to have solve the problem ..

I have seemed to have deleted the ($)row in the row[0] for it to be read properly.
just put $ on the row[0]:

```
echo "<option value=\"row[0]\"";
```

Answer (score 1):

your problem seems to be `echo "<option value=\"row[0]\"";`. You want to replace it with

```
echo "<option value=\"$row[0]\"";
```

`echo "<option value=\"row[0]\"";` just puts a String `row[0]` there

Answer (score 0):

I used to solve this problem like ... In your case.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($request, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
        $cat_id = $row[0];
        $str = null;
        if (isset($_POST['category']) && ($_POST['category'] == $row[0])) {
                $str = 'selected="selected"';
        }
        echo '<option value="'.$row[0].'" '.$str.'>'.$row[1].'</option>';
    }
```