# Selecting the value of a mysql populated drop down list

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to use the value of a mysql populated dropdown list in with php and keep getting a blank return. I have scoured the internet and found very similar questions on here to my problem but everyone i try seems to fail. The select list populates without a problem using the code below.

```
  <form  action="includes/insertEquine.php" method="POST">
        <label for="select-gender" class="select">Choose Gender</label>
        <select name="select-gender id="select-gender">
            <?php
            $sql = ("SELECT genderType FROM gender");
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

                echo "<option value ='".$row['genderType']."'>" . $row['genderType'] . "</option>";
            } ?>
        </select></form>
```

when i try to select it using the below I get an empty space returned.

```
<?php $genderType = $_POST['select-gender']; ?>
```

Any further suggestions would greatfully recived.
I have already looked at the below with no success
[Getting value from populated drop down list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23207043/getting-value-from-populated-drop-down-list)
and
[How to dynamically get the value of a select tag from MySQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16093447/how-to-dynamically-get-the-value-of-a-select-tag-from-mysql-table) .

Comment: What's `<?php>`? It should be `<?php` or `<?php echo '>';` Turning on error reporting would show that. That also isn't in your first code sampling, so maybe it is a typo or your first sample is a simplified version?

Comment: I create the drop down list with no problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `"` in

```
<select name="select-gender id="select-gender">
```

So replace it as

```
<select name="select-gender" id="select-gender">
```

That is why you arent getting a value with key `select-gender` in `$_POST`

Comment: Brilliant thank you very much, looking in the wrong place just the " missing as you said.